# Xamarin Forms Effect

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I create an effect to customize switch element in xamarin forms but i found the error (Specified cast is not valid) in line 15. Any idea to change this?  My class bellow

```
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Widget;
using Puuber.Droid.Platform;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;


[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.ExportEffect(typeof(PinkSwitchEffect), "PinkSwitchEffect")]
namespace Puuber.Droid.Platform
{
class PinkSwitchEffect: PlatformEffect
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        var toggle = (Android.Widget.Switch)Control;
        Xamarin.Forms.Color gold = Xamarin.Forms.Color.FromHex("#fcb741");

        toggle.TrackDrawable.SetColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(gold.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn));      
    }

    protected override void OnDetached()
    {
        // Use this method if you wish to reset the control to original state
    }
}
```

My xaml file is this, the effect add in xaml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Puuber;assembly=Puuber"
    x:Class="Puuber.Welcome">
<AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="#161616">
<Image Source="logo.png" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5 ,0, 1, 0.4" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="XProportional,YProportional,WidthProportional, HeightProportional"/>
  <Label x:Name="rangeText" TextColor="#ffffff" FontSize = "24" Text="5 Km" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.8 ,0.5, 0.25, 0.1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="XProportional,YProportional,WidthProportional, HeightProportional" local:CustomFontEffect.FontFileName="OpenSans-Regular">
      <Label.FontFamily>
          <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
              <OnPlatform.Android></OnPlatform.Android>   
            </OnPlatform>
      </Label.FontFamily>  
  </Label>
  <Slider x:Name="rangeSlider" Maximum="100" Minimum="5" ValueChanged="rangeSlider_ValueChanged" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5 ,0.55, 0.8, 0.1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="XProportional,YProportional,WidthProportional, HeightProportional">
      <Slider.Effects>
          <local:GoldSliderEffect/>
      </Slider.Effects>
  </Slider>
  <Label Text="Mulheres" TextColor="#ffffff" FontSize = "24" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5 ,0.7, 0.5, 0.1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="XProportional,YProportional,WidthProportional, HeightProportional" local:CustomFontEffect.FontFileName="OpenSans-Regular">
      <Label.FontFamily>
          <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
              <OnPlatform.Android></OnPlatform.Android>   
            </OnPlatform>
      </Label.FontFamily>  
  </Label>
<Switch IsToggled="{Binding isOn}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.8 ,0.667, 0.15, 0.05" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="XProportional, YProportional, WidthProportional, HeightProportional">
  <Switch.Effects>
          <local:PinkSwitchEffect/>
      </Switch.Effects>
</Switch>
  <Label Text="Homens" TextColor="#ffffff" FontSize = "24" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5 ,0.80, 0.5, 0.1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="XProportional,YProportional,WidthProportional, HeightProportional" local:CustomFontEffect.FontFileName="OpenSans-Regular">
      <Label.FontFamily>
          <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
              <OnPlatform.Android></OnPlatform.Android>   
            </OnPlatform>
      </Label.FontFamily>  
  </Label>
<Switch IsToggled="{Binding isOn}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.8 ,0.767, 0.15, 0.05" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="XProportional, YProportional, WidthProportional, HeightProportional"/>
<Label Text="Travestis" TextColor="#ffffff" FontSize = "24" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5 ,0.9, 0.5, 0.1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="XProportional,YProportional,WidthProportional, HeightProportional" local:CustomFontEffect.FontFileName="OpenSans-Regular">
      <Label.FontFamily>
          <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
              <OnPlatform.Android></OnPlatform.Android>   
            </OnPlatform>
      </Label.FontFamily>  
  </Label>
  <Switch IsToggled="{Binding isOn}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.8 ,0.867, 0.15, 0.05" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="XProportional, YProportional, WidthProportional, HeightProportional"/>
</AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Can you please include the code where you attach the effect to the control?

Comment: Edited with xaml file now.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your `Control` will be an instance of `Android.Support.V7.Widget.SwitchCompat` instead of `Android.Widget.Switch`. By default the Android MainActivity inherits from `global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity` when you start a new Xamarin Forms project. In that case, a XAML `Switch` will become a `SwitchCompat` instead of a `Android.Widget.Switch`.

You can find out what the type of your `Control` is by looking at the inspector in Visual Studio or Xamarin Studio. So change line 15 to `var toggle = (Android.Support.V7.Widget.SwitchCompat)Control;` if the `Control` has the `SwitchCompat` type.

Since you got to the error, I expect you already did the following, but just to be complete:

Keep in mind that you need a `ResolutionGroupName` assembly attribute in your Android project, and a `RoutingEffect` in your PCL/shared project in order to reference the effect correctly. See https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/effects/creating/ for an example of this.

For reference, this is what the Android renderers create as a native control, based on the MainActivity base class:

- `FormsApplicationActivity`: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/SwitchRenderer.cs#L52
- `FormsAppCompatActivity`: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/AppCompat/SwitchRenderer.cs#L41